How to make one of the users a moderator within a Jitsi Meeting using @jitsi/react-sdk?
We have implemented Jitsi t our platform using @jitsi/react-sdk the meeting has been going very well except for the previous months, as whenever a user of ours join a meeting -which is hosted on jitsi- they have been asked to login into jitsi or wait till a moderator has arrived.
 .
I've a moderator for each meeting but I don't know how to set a moderator for the meeting.
I've tried to override the config of <JaaSMeeting /> component of jists by adding,
participantsPane: { hideModeratorSettingsTab: true, disableModeratorIndicator: true, },
but it didn't work.
